# MS teams github connector - can the body be removed? Only want the title in message

Tags: github, microsoft-teams

I am using the [github connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/github/#definitions) for micrsoft teams. In particular, I am using it for only PR requests.

Is there a way I can remove the body of the notification message? It is very large and disrupting on the team channel. I went into the actual github repo to manage the web hook and I do not see a way I can manually set the JSON payload

I just want a one line sentience... like just have only the title of the PR  `New pull request: "please ignore- testing connector in teams"

Answer (score 2):

As best I can tell, this isn't a configurable feature of the GitHub Connector. There is however a sample available that replicates much of that functionality at https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-nodejs. You may be able to get the functionality you want using this sample and sideload it into your Team.